# c++ input commands into an already opened cmd window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system

This is my code for a console application. The first file "ms00954.exe" is run which opens up a new system cmd window. What I want to do is execute my second command into that new window. How would I approach this? Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  system("C:\\temp\\ms00954.exe -O xp");
  system("C:\\Program Files\\Windows SteadyState\\SCTUI.exe /DisableWDPAndReboot");
  return 0;
}
```

If i run the first program from an open commandline window, it opens up a new system level command line window. What I have to do now is execute the second command in the new window.

I've been looking around and I've come across the "FindWindow" function for WINAPI. Is it possible to use this to get a hold of that new window and then somehow execute the second command with some other function inside this window?

Comment: C++ is the wrong thing for just executing commands. There's no real easy way to grab hold of that window and do something else in it in C++.

Comment: Ahh yea, this is just a tiny part of my entire final year project. I'm sure there are plenty other ways to execute commands. But what I need is what I have stated above. How would I grab hold of that window and execute commands in it with using a batch file then?

Comment: Batch files already have a window that gets reused. Why not just start a batch file from C++ then? Alternatively, depending on what the commands do, you could just wrap up `CreateProcess` in a function and use that to execute these programs.

Comment: Just tried running a batch file with these commands:

    echo

    "C:\\temp\\ms11-080.exe" -O xp

    "C:\\Program Files\\Windows SteadyState\\SCTUI.exe" /DisableWDPAndReboot

Same thing happens, the second command does not execute in the newly opened cmd window :(
The thing is, the first application opens up a new cmd window, and I want to execute that second command in that window.

Comment: What happens if you run the either program from an open commandline window? If that opens another window, that application explicitly calls AllocConsoleWindow() (or whatever its name was), which is IMHO a bug and nothing that you can change. If they both write to the initial window, you might get away compiling the C++ code as console application or by calling AllocConsoleWindow() yourself first.

Comment: write the batch file with only the second command in it and not the first.... will that do it for you? or possibly write a batch file that says:   `start       @echo (command...)`               with a new line between the start and @echo?

Comment: even if i only have the second command in the batch file, i will still have to somehow get a hold of that new cmd window and execute this batch file in it :S

Comment: add a && in between your two commands